# How do I decompress/expand records while generating my dataset?

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

I am trying to generate a dataset for reporting in our wave analytics (Einstein Analytics) app. The source for this data will be an object in salesforce however I need to transform this data for the purpose of our reporting. I need to transform it as follows -

A record in my target object has the following fields - Start Date, End Date, Total Amount. I need this data transformed in such a manner that this one record is expanded into as many records as the no. of days between start date and end date while the amount is pro rated.

For Example - 1 Existing Record - {Start Date : 1st Aug 2017; End Date : 5th Aug 2017; Total Amount : 50}

After the transformation, I should get 5 records each for 1 date in the date range like -

- Record 1 {Start Date : 1st Aug 2017; End Date : 1st Aug 2017; Total
         Amount : 10}
- Record 2 {Start Date : 2nd Aug 2017; End Date : 2nd Aug
         2017; Total Amount : 10}
- Record 3 {Start Date : 3rd Aug 2017; End
         Date : 3rd Aug 2017; Total Amount : 10}
- Record 4 {Start Date : 4th
         Aug 2017; End Date : 4th Aug 2017; Total Amount : 10}
- Record 5
         {Start Date : 5th Aug 2017; End Date : 5th Aug 2017; Total Amount :
         10}

Is such a data transformation even possible in wave ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using compute function of data flow or bucket field of recipes by definition.As of my knowledge, i am unfamiliar with bucket field but you can achieve this by compute function of dataflow if you have a saql query that can achieve this

Comment: Actually such a transformation is not feasible on the analytics platform. We confirmed this with the product specialist @ SF.

We ended up running this transformation externally and then pushing the data into the analytics app.

Answer (score 0):

If your still looking and considering above example.

create a compute expression calculate the date difference between startdate and enddate. and divide it with the amount so you individual amount.